# Making a model of an Intel 80386

Tags: microprocessor, processor

On the internet there are some die shots of the 80386 but I am having a hard time finding one that contains descriptions or interpretations of each of its components. I need to make a model, and for that I need some representation to distinguish the different parts of the die shot and resemble the block diagram of the respective 386.

Should I stick with only using block diagrams for the model?

Comment: Reverse-engineering a chip to the transistor level is not a simple process, and probably can't be done from just looking at the die. You'd need to etch away the layers one at a time to see all the interconnects, at the very least; there's not just one metal layer on a chip as complex as a 386.

Comment: Yes, stick with the block diagram.  The '386 contains ~275,000 transistors.  Do you really think you can reverse engineer down to that level?  You may have luck doing that for an early generation uP, like the 4004 or 8080, but for something like the '386.

Comment: You may find one of Ken Shirriff's ongoing projects helpful: https://www.righto.com/2023/11/reverse-engineering-intel-386.html how detailed you make the model depends on what you need it to do.